# Report Services crashes in visual studio debugger for local report when page number parameters are added

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

I have a report that looks like this:

[image: Report]

There isn't anything really special about the report, it's my first report I've made with reporting services for my application (we're transitioning from crystal reports).

It's a local report that runs fine outside of visual studio. However, if I run it inside visual studio with that bottom right corner textbox (the expression is `=Globals.PageNumber & " of " & Globals.TotalPages`) it crashes. If I remove the box, it runs.

It crashes with this error code:

> The assembly with display name
>   'expression_host_9191d5a6e4724724b792f551d1c7a8e9'
>   failed to load in the 'LoadFrom'
>   binding context of the AppDomain with
>   ID 1. The cause of the failure was:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could
>   not load file or assembly
>   'expression_host_9191d5a6e4724724b792f551d1c7a8e9,
>   Version=11.2.30319.1, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find
>   the file specified.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a shot in the dark but my next move would be to disable the Visual Studio hosting process.

- Right Click on project and select Properties
- Go to the Debug Tab
- Uncheck "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process"

It's possible this particular project type doesn't support the hosting process in which case it will be grayed out (and I'll be wrong :) ).

Comment: @Malfist, damn. Have you tried the standard "disable func eval", "disable just my code" tricks?